# Parse Issue Key from JIRA Rest API using Powershell

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

I am setting up an automated process for JIRA using System Center Orchestrator and Powershell. In this example I already have the raw JSON data from the JIRA Rest API.

```
function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){ 
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer

    #The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell
    return ,$ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}

[object]$JSON = '{Raw JSON Data from JIRA Variable}'

$results = ConvertFrom-Json20($JSON)

$key = @()
$count = @()
foreach( $issue in $results.issues ) { 
    $key += $issue.key
    $count += $key.count
}

$key = @($key | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null})
$count = @($count | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null})
```

The server I am using doesn't have the latest Powershell package so that's why I have the `ConvertFrom-Json20([object])` function included. In SCORCH the `$key` and `$count` are the Published Data variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code above you can get the Issue Key field from the JSON data from JIRA Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

For the powershell issue, if you install version 3.0 or later on the server, you have a couple approaches to replacing the json conversion function.

1. Regiser and deploy the following integration pack:
   http://orchestrator.codeplex.com/releases/view/76101
2. Execute the powershell within a Powershell script block for the Run .NET Script activity:
   https://automys.com/library/asset/powershell-system-center-orchestrator-practice-template

I'm not understanding why you need to iterate through the keys and store the 1 based value of the current index for the key.  Given the above about powershell, the following would give you the same results you have shown.  Where you consume they $key array would need to account for the current index of the element being zero based:

```
$results = ConvertFrom-Json $JSON
$key = $results.issues | Where-Object {$_.key -ne $null}
```